# Pywinauto identifier is Empty

Tags: python-3.x, ui-automation, pywinauto

When i print the identifiers of the dialog following is the output

```
Qt5QWindowIcon - 'b'widget_fenetre_openglWindow''   (L395, T202, R1046,B602)

'b'Qt5QWindowIcon20''
'b'widget_fenetre_openglWindow''
'b'widget_fenetre_openglWindowQt5QWindowIcon''

Qt5QWindowGLOwnDCIcon - 'b'''   (L400, T202, R1040, B602)

'b'''
'b'Qt5QWindowGLOwnDCIcon''
```

there are other identifiers above as well, i need to know what

```
 Qt5QWindowGLOwnDCIcon - 'b'''   (L400, T202, R1040, B602)
```

means, how can i access that element  from pywinauto, 
or is it some unaccessible element not relevant to ui?

Comment: pywinauto 0.5.4 doesn't support Qt apps well. But you may try `UIA` branch from gtihub repo for early testing. You just need to install `comtypes` as an additional dependency and use `Application(backend="uia")`. Any feedback would be great.

Comment: thanks for responding, since im a beginner i need to know how can i get the UIA branch of pywinauto to work. do i clone it and build from source?

Comment: Just switch from master to UIA branch on GitHub, download as ZIP, unpack and run `python setup.py install`

Comment: `comtypes` can be installed by `pip install -U comtypes`

Comment: yes i was able to it, but it didn't change the problem i had,
however i was able to do what i wanted using another approach.
thank you @VasilyRyabov